# Fourier Transform negative discrepancy

Tags: fourier-transform

My teacher wrote on the board for Fourier Transforms for $f(x)$ from $-\infty<x<\infty$:

$$F(\mu)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{i\mu x}dx$$ and for the inverse transform
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\mu)e^{-i\mu x}\frac{d\mu}{2\pi}$$

Notice where I have the negatives in the exponents...
My confusion is that I see the following all over online:

$$F(\mu)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\mu x}dx$$ and for the inverse transform
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\mu)e^{i\mu x}\frac{d\mu}{2\pi}$$ 
with the non-negative in the inverse transform. But I can't find the version that my teacher wrote.

1) I am trying to figure out if they are equivalent somehow or if there was a mistake in class.

2) Also, if there was not a mistake, would both forms give the same answer in the end of problems? Or is there some kind of change of variable that happens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The two forms are equivalent.

But the second form is indeed the preferred one at 99.9 %. I see at least two reasons for that :

- It can be seen as the **hermitian** (dot) product (usual for complex-valued functions) :

$$\langle f,g \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$$ where $g(x):=e^{i\mu x}$.

- It generalizes to non integer values the formula giving complex $c_n$ coefficients for a Fourier **series**. See for example the exchange in ([Computing Coefficients of Complex Form Fourier Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/116591)).